# Are testing website URLs considered duplicate content and do they trigger penalties?

Tags: duplicate-content, canonical-url, testing, noindex, penalty

I have a website with several thousand pages and I generate a small version of it (100 pages) which I upload to a temporary `testing.mywebsite.com` URL for testing purposes.

Yet, it could be seen as duplicate content considering the live website on a different URL. Should I be worried about this? Can I get a penalty for this?

I was considering setting canonical links to the main website or setting no index on the pages generated for testing. Is it necessary to do so? Would it help?

Comment: Why would you even want this to be crawled?

Comment: I don't want it to be crawled, but one way or the other, Google could learn about it.

Comment: Block it every way possible. Basic authentication, robots.txt, x-robots-tag, etc. Make sure they **never** see it.

Comment: `Google could learn about it` Learn from what exactly?

Comment: I use adsense, so adsense may notice the ad call from my testing website, and inform Google robots may be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search engines might …

1. … find your testing website.
2. … index pages from your testing website.
3. … decide that a page from the real site and the testing site are duplicate copies, so they might only index one of those pages.

If you are unlucky, they might decide to index the testing page instead of the real page in some cases (especially, if not all of your real pages are indexed yet).

> I was considering setting canonical links to the main website or setting no index on the pages generated for testing. Is it necessary to do so? Would it help?

Yes, it would help (for those search engines that support `canonical` resp. `robots`-`noindex`).